# How to send file from PHP-script to another PHP-script in code?

Tags: php, file-upload

I have some web-form which posts some data and user file to **first php script**.
First script wants to upload received from form file which located at $_FILE variable to **second php script** (second script wants receive file in $_FILE variable too).

How can I make this?

P.S. Second script located on another web-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use a `curl`.
For example: http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html

Answer (score 1):

Include the "**second php script**" in "**first php script**" after the file is uploaded. Otherwise, you cannot "send" a file to another PHP script.

```
if( isset( $_FILE['file']))
{
    // Process file upload
    if( move_uploaded_file( ...))
    {
        include "second_php_script.php";
    }
}
```

Comment: second script located at another server

Comment: If you have URL wrappers enabled you can include a remote file. See http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php, example #3. Or you can use cURL to send the file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use POST request with base64_encode/base64_decode functions for transporting binary data. Thanks all.